# Avoid getting an array of id in results (mssql - node.js)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

I recently started to work with mssql (SQLServer) instead of mySQL.
So I updated my routes to work with mssql.

However I encountered a problem :
When I use a join for example, with 2 tables that have a column 'Id', I got an array of Id instead of a single Id. (both ids are the same)

Is that possible to get only a single id, and not an array ?
Thank you in advance !

```
  const query = 'SELECT sessions.*, chiffres.*, participants.*\
  FROM dbo.sessions\
  INNER JOIN dbo.participants ON participants.id = sessions.id\
  INNER JOIN dbo.chiffres ON chiffres.id = participants.id'

  return ps.prepare(query, err => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({ errors: { sql: err } })
    }
    return ps.execute(optsValues, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ errors: { sql: err } })
      }
      return ps.unprepare(err => {
        if (err) {
          return res.json({ errors: { sql: err } })
        }

        return res.json({ sessions: results?.recordset })
      })
    })
  })
```

results.recordset =>

```
[
    {
        "id": [2, 2, 2],
        "num_session": "blabla"
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: What do your tables look like structure-wise?

Comment: @PeterKA 

Sessions :
id: Int PK
num_session: nvarchar

chiffres:
id: Int PK
ca: decimal

participants:
id: Int PK
name: nvarchar


They all have the same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar so much with javascript, but as the COLUMN is exactly the same name in each table and you have not aliased the columns then how do you expect the client to separate them out?

It is generally poor practice to use table.* in your queries since the table structure may change over time and your code would not immediately error and perhaps cause adverse impacts dopwnstream. Always be specific with the columns you want to choose.

Try something like this for the query:

```
const query = 'SELECT sessions.id as SessionID, sessions.num_session, chiffres.id as ChiffresID, chiffres.ca, participants.id as ParticipantID, participants.name\
FROM dbo.sessions\
INNER JOIN dbo.participants ON participants.id = sessions.id\
INNER JOIN dbo.chiffres ON chiffres.id = participants.id'
```

Comment: Yes but SSMS knows how to handle it for example.
But thank you, that is the solution a was thinking about, and I will use it